# UITextField remove "..."

Tags: ios, cocoa, uitextfield

I have a problem with UITextField and my best friend google don't want help me...

I would to remove the "..." automatically added at the end of the field if is content is too long. Is it possible?

Comment: hey here alternative solution here your text field display with its content size with both side...see my bellow code...

Answer (score 0):

This is "truncate tail" of LineBreaks property in xib file. You can change to "word wrap" for example.

Comment: Thanks but my UITextField isn't declared in my xib.
The apple UITextField Class Reference doesn't have this property.
How to set it programmatically?

Comment: My mistake. Truncate tail for labels. All text fields just scroll right, aren't they? I've never seen "..." with textfilds.

Try 'Matic Oblak' solution or use xib files.

Comment: @kaspartus You have "..." on UITextField but it's on the right side

Answer (score 0):

What if you made an UILabel and do as "kaspartus" described and put UITextField over it at same position and size with clear background and text color. Then just add target to text field on 'UIControlEventEditingChanged' and set the label's text to text field's text.
This solution is not what you are really supposed to do, but if it works..

Answer (score 0):

here you  use your own size ..

```
yourTextField.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, yourTextField.contentVerticalAlignment);
```

and also for horizontal alignment
use bellow code

```
_positionTextField.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, _positionTextField.contentHorizontalAlignment, 44);
```

also you can use both...
hope this help you....
:)

Comment: What happens if content is really too long?

Comment: yes right que., i think best solution is take textview insted of textfield give the multiple line true with your requirement otherview you put the textfield in scrollview and then give the textfield contentsize.... here this 2 solution of your problem... :)

Comment: and also if you use scrollview then here you must give the contentSize to scrollview and you can give the dynamic contentSize with this line.. yourScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, yourTextField.contentVerticalAlignment+5);

Comment: It's just a question. Does the right bound go outside a view of controller?

Comment: I didn't understand your code clearly. You change height of textfild's frame, not width(it's just 320). It's ok, but textfield has only one line, and we talk about too long content.

Comment: hey dude so i just tell you you can use textview insted of textfield and its too easy i use this but with here you can declare contentsize with this line its very easy and work fine just try this code but with textView..    yourTextView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, yourTextView.contentSize.height); please not use textfield in this code just use textView... :)